# Google Play Games: messaging other players

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I was wondering if it's possible to message other players (both friends and strangers) via the Google Play Games app?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if your game uses the [real-time multiplayer API](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer) in Google Play games services, as stated in sending game data:

> You can use the Google Play games services to broadcast data to participants in a room, or allow participants to exchange messages with each other. Data messages can be sent using a reliable or unreliable messaging protocol provided by Google Play games services.